# LinkedList cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, linked-list

First here is my code:

```
package linkedlist;

public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

        list.addAtFront("Sachar");
        list.addAtFront("Osborne");
        list.addAtFront("Suess");
        System.out.println(list);

        list.remove("Suess");
        list.remove("Sachar");
        list.remove("Osborne");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

I am also using NetBeans.

Whenever I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol

list.addAtFront(java.lang.String);
symbol:   method addAtFront(String)
location: variable list of type LinkedList


error: cannot find symbol

list.remove(java.lang.String);
symbol:   method addAtFront(String)
location: variable list of type LinkedList
```

Please help me out here. I copied the code exactly from an example so it's not an error I made.

Comment: Did you want to use `java.util.LinkedList`?If so,You shouldn't implemented it by yourself,But just import it.

Comment: It is a bad idea to name your class the same as a (frequently used) library class.  You are liable to pick up the wrong one by mistake ... like you did here.

Answer (score 2):

The example must have had a custom `LinkedList` class, and not put `main` inside `LinkedList`.  You, on the other hand, are trying to place your code inside `LinkedList` and not defining any methods other than `main`.  Since you didn't define `addAtFront` or `remove` on your `LinkedList` class, the compiler can't find either.

Assuming that you're new to Java, I recommend following [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to learn the language.  At first, just follow "Trails covering the basics," and once you get a good feel for Java build some practice applications.  As you encounter the issues associated with building software, you will feel the need to hit the other Java tutorials trails that are relevant to you.

Comment: Yeah, turned out my text was using a custom LinkedList class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using another LinkedList class (possibly declared in the same package). Rename your custom code to MyLinkedList.java instead of LinkedList.java and recompile. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do ..

http://northern.lkdsb.net/kedwell/ICS4U/DataStructures/linked_list.htm

In the Link ,They have **Linked List** Class ,in that there is a method for placing the element in the first which is created by the user.There,they are trying to implement the concept of Linked List in Data Structures.And the function is

```
public void addAtFront(String str) {
    Node newNode = new Node(str);
    newNode.setNext(head);
    head = newNode;
}
```

In the java.util.LinkedList ,There is no method named **addAtFront**(). Please find the Java Docs link below :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

I hope this would be helpful to you.